# Cannot change the frame of a UILabel in a Custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, frame, uicollectionviewcell

I am making a Custom `CollectionViewCell` and so far so good.

---

**The Setup:**

1. Storyboard with a `UICollectionView` on a `UIViewController`.
2. Created a `UICollectionViewCell` which has the layout details of the cell on it.
3. Object that are required in the cell are set up in the storyboard.

---

**Objective**

- To want to give a different layout when the device is portrait or landscape.

---

**Problems**

1) I think it has something to do with the `Autolayout`, but I do not want to turn it off, because I need it for the rest of the project.

2) Please refer to the code below:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        _collectionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 40);
        _collectionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        _collectionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else
    {
        _collectionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 40);
        _collectionLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        _collectionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

Now all off the code above works, except that the frame of the `UILabel` does not change.
If I turn `Autolayout` off for the project then it does work.

---

**Question**

What do I need to adjust to the code above for the cell to pick up the frame change when the device is rotated?
Everything else works - that is the only problem.
Once I have this working I can produce the rest of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using auto layout, you shouldn't set any frames. Instead, you should adjust the constraints, or in some cases, remove some and add others. The easiest way to do this, is to make IBOutlets to the constraints in IB, and then modify their constant value in code (the constant value, ironically, is the only parameter of a constraint that can be changed). It's not clear from your question, which of the frame parameters you're trying to change, but say you had an outlet to a constraint called leftCon, you would change it like so,

```
self.leftCon.constant = 20;
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, except I am setting this within a cell, so I cannot use your answer. _collectionLabel is a UILabel and I need to change the top position (y) from 20 to 100.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg, why can't you use my answer? There's no reason you can't use this within a cell. Make an outlet to the constraint to the top of the cell, and change its constant value to 100.

Comment: Sorry I read your question wrong, just got to sort the NSLayoutConstraint that goes with what I need...